# How do I get real screen size in inches of a device?

Tags: android, screen-size

I'm trying to find the REAL screen size in inches of a device. I tested with `getRealMetrics()`, but the code does not work well on all the devices.

For example on NEXUS 5 it works fine and tells that the device haves 4.96 inches, but in BQ Aquaris E5 FHD with KitKat 4.4.2 it does not work well and tells that the device have 4.59 inches (it has 5 inches...)

This is the code that does not work properly:

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRealMetrics(displayMetrics);        
double d1 = displayMetrics.widthPixels / displayMetrics.xdpi;
double d2 = displayMetrics.heightPixels / displayMetrics.ydpi;
double deviceInches = Math.sqrt(d1 * d1 + d2 * d2);
```

Comment: Have you tried dividing `deviceInches` by `density` or maybe `densityDpi`?

Comment: i dont understand you, if i divide deviceInches i will get a lower value and not a real screen inches value

Comment: Ah I am sorry I got it wrong. I did not realize you were dividing the width and height by their density. What I wanted to say was try finding the diagonal length of the screen in pixels and then divide that by the density

Comment: If you have a look at WikiPedia on how they calculate the screen density(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_density) you will see that they do it based on the diagonal of the screen

Comment: Then the manufacturer has a bug in this device, presumably somewhere in their density values. Please contact the manufacturer and ask them to fix their device.